# how to implement allPaths or allSimplePaths algorithms in Neo4j using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im trying to find all paths between two nodes in neo4j db

the query i used to get all paths returns error, while it works when I change allSimplePaths to shortestPath to get the shortest path:

```
MATCH (from), (to) , 
paths = allSimplePaths((from)-[*]->(to)) 
WHERE from.ID ='3007' AND to.ID in ['5575','8150', '3674']
Return paths
```

returns error message:

```
Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property 
map, a relationship pattern, ',', USING, WHERE, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, 
MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or 
end of input (line 2, column 23 (offset: 82))
"paths = allSimplePaths((from)-[*]->(to)) "
```

Comment: Are you sure you want "all paths"? That's potentially a lot of data and has serious performance implications.

Comment: Im still experimenting with my data to find an optimal query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allSimplePaths` and `allPaths` are [graph algorithms](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html) supported by the neo4j REST API, but not Cypher.

To get the equivalent of `allPaths`, you could just do this:

```
MATCH (from), (to), paths = (from)-[*]->(to)
WHERE from.ID ='3007' AND to.ID in ['5575','8150', '3674']
Return paths
```

You will need to use the REST API to use `allSimplePaths`.